# How can I check if a document id that already exists in Firestore using Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection with one document id previously added into Firestore (see image below).
I would like to know how can I check if that document id already exists so it can say like "document exists"

This is the code I have so far:

```
 void submit() async {
    final snapShot =
        await Firestore.instance.collection('books').document().get();
    if (snapShot.exists) {
      print('document exists');
    } else {
       print('document does not exists');
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: What you're doing now is the best you can do.  The only way to check if a document exists is to `get()` it and check the `exists` property.

Comment: thanks, sir, but actually I was looking a way to check if a document already existed but without providing any document id to get(), I wanted the user to get subscribed into something in the app just by choosing an option in a dropdown and clicking the subscribed button, I don't want the users to input any data as the user was already signed up, thanks anyways

Comment: If you don't know the ID, then you'll need to know some other value(s) that unique identifies the document you're looking for. Once you know that, you can use a query to find document(s) that match that value(s).

Comment: Right, but I dont want

Comment: Right, but I dont want the user to provide any data as it would be an extra step and at this point the user has already signed up but I think I found a way to do that,  the first time the user tries to subscribe insted of check if it's exist, it will check if snapshot is false and will create the doc id and save it into a provider so the second time the user tries to subscribe again will check if the user already exits by taking the id from the provider that was saved before, the problem that I face now it's that when I hot restart the app, the provider gets obviously empty